# What measure should I use as cross-validation error with logistic regression in K-fold cross-validation?

Tags: logistic, cross-validation

What measure should I use as cross-validation error with logistic regression in K-fold cross-validation, especially when the Type I error is more serious and what we want to avoid at all cost?

Comment: Logistic regression is not really technically theoretically a classification algorithm but it essentially is so, so classification measures are relevant here. But I don't really see why you are talking about Type I errors and CV (which is about predictions) in the same sentence. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am applying logistic regression with regularization. When cross-validation is performed to choose the regularization parameter, I need a measure as the criteria. In this case study, type I errors are more dangerous than type II errors.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of your figure of merit (aka loss function or error) depends on a few things. Interestingly, that you want to perform $k$-fold cross validation isn't one of those!

The idea is that your figure of merit needs to be suitable for your task at hand. I.e. it needs to answer the spelled-out questions you want to answer about your model's performance.

- If you want to compare several models/optimize your model (logistic regression vs. other models, or hyperparameter tuning), it is important to use a so-called [*(strictly) proper scoring rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule). These are figures of merit that yield their optimum iff the predicted probability (of the logistic regression) equals the actual probability.
  Note that sensitivity, specificity, accuracy and the predictive values are *no* proper scoring rules.
- However, if you need to talk, say, to medical doctors about your model, you may need to calcualate figures of merit like sensitivity, specificity, predictive values etc. (even though they are mathematically not as well behaved as the proper scoring rules).
- Cross validation does not limit you to calculation of a single figure of merit: it primarily provides you with predictions for a set of test cases, and you are free to calculate as many figures of merit as you need.

You say that type-I-error, which I assume to translate to a false positive, is more serious [than false negative]. Have a look at the concept of misclassification costs. However, avoiding literally *at all cost* will get you a trivial model that *never* predicts positive.

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming your are performing LASSO or RIDGE (or both) regression, there the optimal $\lambda$ parameter is chosen based on CV and a default measure (MSE I believe, or maybe deviance). What you need is a measure that does not give equal weight to the classes (errors). There are a few such measures, most common is probably the F-score (F1). Alternatively you could look at both Sensitivity and Specificity together (taken from a confusion matrix). This is what an AUROC curve does. It's a nice plot which shows both previous measures on the same graph and how they change with different cut off points.